# NUnit is not showing Debug messages in its window

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nunit, moq

I'm using NUnit 262 and VS 2010.

This code should show messages writen with Debug.Writeline in the NUnit window, but it doen't.

The code:

```
public interface ILongRunningLibrary {
    string RunForALongTime(int interval);
}

public class LongRunningLibrary : ILongRunningLibrary {
    public string RunForALongTime(int interval) {
        var timeToWait = interval * 1000; Thread.Sleep(timeToWait);
        return string.Format("Waited {0} seconds", interval);
    }
}
[TestFixture]
public class MoqExamples {
    private Mock<ILongRunningLibrary> _longRunningLibrary;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetupForTest() {
        _longRunningLibrary = new Mock<ILongRunningLibrary>();
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestLongRunningLibrary() {
        const int interval = 10;
        var result = _longRunningLibrary.Object.RunForALongTime(interval);
        Debug.WriteLine("Return from method was '" + result + "'");
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDownAfterTest() {
    }
}
```

I should see this in the NUnit window:

[image: a busy cat]

But I see this instead:

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `Console.WriteLine`, you'll see the output in the `Text Output` tab at the bottom of the test runner. I'm not sure if `Debug.WriteLine` puts it there as well. Have you checked?

Comment: Yes, I checked but there's no message in that tab either. That tab is even gray, as if it was disabled!!

Comment: Is it an option to replace Debug.WriteLine with Console.WriteLine? And does that even work?